# Access Connected to SQL Server: Get User Name in Form Query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ms-access-2010

I use Access with linked tables to SQL Server 2008 R2 (ODBC connection). Via a access form I select the following query when opening the access form (the query code is entered in Design View > Form Properties > Record Source):

```
SELECT 
    mp_industry_description.group_name, 
    mp_industry_description.industry_description 
FROM 
((ax_id_storage 
INNER JOIN 
mn_entity 
ON ax_id_storage.id_bb_global_company = mn_entity.id_bb_global_company) 

INNER JOIN 
mp_industry 
ON mn_entity.industry_subroup_num = mp_industry.subgroup_num) 

INNER JOIN 
mp_industry_description 
ON mp_industry.industry_description_group_num = mp_industry_description.industry_group_num;
```

The query works fine. Table ax_id_storage contains a column with all possible user names (userID). Therefore, the above query gives me several row entries, one for each user. I want to have only one user, which is the one who is currently executing the query. In a SQL Server query, I can adjust for this by adding:

```
WHERE ax_id_storage.userID = (SELECT nt_username FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE (spid = @@SPID));
```

at the end of the first query. However, this does not work when I use the exact same command in Access. I get an error:

> Syntax error in query expression 'ax_id_storage.userID = (SELECT
>   nt_username FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE (spid = @@SPID))'.

How can I get the user name in Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. There were three problems with my code:

First, I had to link the table sys.sysprocesses from the SQL server into Access.

Second, the command

> WHERE ax_id_storage.userID = (SELECT nt_username FROM sys.sysprocesses
>   WHERE (spid = @@SPID));

had to be changed into

> WHERE ax_id_storage.userID = (SELECT nt_username FROM
>   sys.sysprocesses)

as @@SPID is not executable in Access, onlny in SQL Server itself.

And third, Access does not allow INNER JOINS concatenated without parentheses. Therefore, I had to add them in the following way:

> Select a FROM (table1 INNER JOIN table 2 ON table1.a = table2.a) INNER
>   JOIN table 3 on [...]

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar topic with ODBC, attached tables and ADO connections from the same MS Access Client to a SQL Server DB. There I have found the "nt_username" not working. However, the you have 3 or more different connections the "hostaddress" is a good thing to use.

I first insert a record containing the username into a table (secUserSession_tbl) on the server (with the respective @@SPID) and then I use the following view to propagate the username to all sessions from the same host:

```
CREATE VIEW secSessionUser_vw
AS
SELECT su.UserID, su.Login from sys.sysprocesses as sp 
INNER JOIN secSessionUser_tbl AS su ON sp.hostprocess = su.hostprocess
WHERE sp.hostprocess  = (SELECT hostprocess FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE spid = @@SPID)
```

This view can now be joined with every table or view and returns a username and/or respective permissions.